# Displaying saved String value in GraphView

Tags: java, android, xml, graph

So I have a data saved on various TextView saved with SharedPreferences. User can edit that data and it works like a charm.. But now I want ALL of the user values for single item to be saved on a Graph, something like progress tracking.

For example, if users weight on the first of January was 220 lbs and on the first of Ferbruary 210 lbs, I want both data entered by the user displayed in Graph so they can track progress. And every time user inputs new data I need it to be displayed with new dot on graph.

I ran into an error, tried to set DataPoint of graph to the saved user input but that's not working..

Anyway, here's the code:

XML:

```
<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:id="@+id/graph" />
```

Java:

```
public class StatistikaGrafoviMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tezinaMetricRezultat;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistika_grafovi_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        tezinaMetricRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
        tezinaMetricRezultat.setText(settings.getString("tezinaMetricSave", "..."));

        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
                new DataPoint(1, 1),
                new DataPoint(1, 5),
                new DataPoint(2, 3),
                new DataPoint(3, 2),
                new DataPoint(4, 6)
        });
        graph.addSeries(series);


    }

}
```

As you can see I tried to acces SharedPreference file but can't get it working.

If anyone knows solution, please let me know!

Comment: is the problem that you can't retrieve your prefs or that the graph doesn't display data? How are you setting your prefs?

Comment: FYI, If you change your question title to "what is the best way to locally store historical data..." or something generic like that you will get more users to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is, but I can recommend using a content provider and storing data rows in the mysql of the phone.

That way you can store large amounts of data like:
User: myUser
date: today
weight: 150lb
...

it's not too complicated and there are many tutorials on how to use a content provider like this one: [contentProvider - youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TN8KfUBD5v8).

Comment: Thanks. The graph displays just fine but not with the values I want. User has some EditText fields to enter numbers and that numbers he entered are displayed on main screen of the app in TextView. I wan't that data to be displayed also in the Graph but i wan't all the values user ever entered to be displayed, that's why I said progress tracking. I have the data saved with Sharedpreferences and for the TextViews it works just fine, so I thought it wouldn't be any different with Graphs

Comment: So if you save to shared prefs you override the past entries? is that the question,how to store past data?

Comment: Yes, that is the question, how to store past data

Comment: The best way is with the content provider. if you insist on shared prefs you can save the data as a string array or give every pref you save a number and call it with the number. That said, you should really be using the content provider for this, that's what it was created for.

Comment: So I created database with this tutorial http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/12/make-android-apps-20/ It saves data and everything I need. Can you teel me how to acces that data with graph?

Comment: You load a cursor using query and ask for whichever data you need to display, for example: give me all the rows for user monkeyfish, then in your cursor's while loop add a row to LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series

Comment: while(cursor.hasNext()){ series.add(new Datapoint(cursor.getColumn(0),cursor.getColumn(1)))} or something

Comment: Can I still do it with SharedPreferences? I'm new to Android so content provider and databases are too complicated for me.. Can you explain me how to do it with  SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using shared prefs (Which is wrong for this sort of task),
you can create a shared preference array for each user, for example:

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("150");
    set.add("200");

    settings.edit().putStringSet("userId", set);


    Set<String> prefSet = settings.getStringSet("userId", null);
    String[] vals = prefSet.toArray(new String[prefSet.size()]);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

    for (int i=0;i<vals.length;i++){
        series.add(new DataPoint(vals[i], i));
    }
```

Another way is to save a json object as a string:

```
   {"user": "MonkeyFish","values:[val1,val2,val-n]}
```

Then you can parse it as a Json object to get the values.

Comment: DataPoint  is from your code, I'm not building the app, just answering questions, This is a Q&A website, not codecademy.

Answer (score 0):

you  have to generate a value array for datapoint like this

```
private DataPoint[] generateData() {
    DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[count];
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        double x = a[i];
        int y = b[i];
        DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x, y);
        values[i] = v;
    }
    return values;
}
```

in place of x and y arrays you can insert the values from your database into the arrays.

then call it in your function like this

```
LineGraphSeries series1 = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(generateData());
graph.addSeries(series1);
```

it generates dynamic graph.  TRIED AND TESTED